Wiring USB-C connector to micro-USB
I have some problems wiring the micro-USB cable to a USB-C connector. I have used the wiring scheme found here, but neither the data are transferred nor the power is supplied to the device.
The connector is slightly different, so I put here the picture of the soldered connector.

Thanks for your help.

Which type of adapter you are making? That's a Type-C plug alright, but what's on the other side, a MicroUSB plug or receptacle? Which end plugs to a host (e.g. a computer) and which end plugs into a device? Can you make a diagram of your wiring? What resistors there are or are there any, and where do they connect? Do they connect to VBUS or GND?

The adapter has two plugs, one Type-C to be inserted in the host and, on the other side a MicroUSB to be plugged into the device. On the connector there is one resistor named "R1" on the PCB. Unfortunately I do not have the wiring scheme

OK, so where is the Type-C plug from; is it a plug assembly for connecting to a host (UFP) or connecting to a device (DFP)? You likely need to double-check what resistor value it has and where it connects to.

Here you can find the connectors and in the images there is also a picture that shows what corresponds to each pad, but I do not have found anything related neither to resistor nor to connectivity type. Connectors

That link to a web page has a button you can click for details and it tells you about the resistor, indicating it being the wrong type of plug.

You have bought a wrong Type-C plug, a host-simulating plug intended for plugging it into a device, signaling to a device that it can draw the default amount of current.
But what you want to do needs a device-simulating Type-C plug intended for plugging into a host, which signals the host to output 5V to your MicroUSB device.
Fortunately, it looks like you can modify the plug type. It currently has a 56k resistor from VBUS to CC pin.
The photos are poor but the empty resistor pads are for connecting a resistor from GND to CC.
You need to put a 5.1k resistor to the empty place and remove the 56k resistor.
Verify first with multimeter which resistor pads are VBUS, GND and CC to see if modifying is possible or if you must buy another plug.

What you are building is a cable assembly fully defined in the USB Type-C spec v2.3. See section 3.5.7 USB Type-C to USB 2.0 Micro-B Cable Assembly on page 87.
Aside from connecting VBus, Ground D+ and D- pins, you need a 5.1kΩ resistor from A5 to Ground (see Table 3-18 note 1). This resistor tells the Type-C receptacle you'll plug into that this cable is meant to connect to a device and port should reconfigure as DFP, then supply VBus.
On the paddle board attached to the Type-C plug, this may be R1 or R2 (cannot tell on the photos). You should probably probe the footprints to see which one is connected to A5.
